# .map function not working with .slice in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to standardise the formatting of today's date, and date's listed on a google sheet. In order to do this, I have pulled the column's into an array, and am trying to map & slice to get rid of the times on the end of a date. However, the slice is simply returning the first 11 data points. I.e. it is not slicing the individual strings, and instead the array as a whole. Any help would be great, as I am very knew to the function.

```js
function getDateColum(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Rota")
  var dateHeaders = ss.getRange('E3:ND3').getValues();
  var date = new Date()
  date = date + ""
  date = date.slice(0,11)
  dateHeaders = dateHeaders.map(function(x){ return x.slice(0,11); })
  Logger.log(date)
  Logger.log(dateHeaders)
}
```

Comment: To get part of a string you need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring (slice is for arrays) it's also not slicing the array as a whole inside the map function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. I have tried replacing slice with substring, but I now get an error for the following code - dateHeaders = dateHeaders.map(function(x){ return x.substring(0,11)}). Error is "x.subsitring is not a function". Any ideas?

Comment: Your `x` is still a Date, not a String. You need to do the same as in your `date` code and turn the Date into a string first. Quick fix: `x => x.toString().substring(0, 10)` The proper way: use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your help. This is now slicing as normal, however is only returning the first data point (Sun Jan 31). It is being stored in an array but only the first piece of data is being sliced

Comment: Also put `Logger.log(dateHeaders)` before the `.map()` line. What is the exact before and after? (you should also remove / comment the lines dealing with `date`, at least while debugging this) I have no idea what the problem is but this is a very trivial operation so we cannot help you without more info: https://jsfiddle.net/vtfw5nag/

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies. I now think the issue stems from the getValue function from google app scripts. I believe this is storing the rows as one big string and not in an array. do you know how to recitfy that aspect of it?

Comment: Did you log `dateHeaders` before the .map call like I asked? What's the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232530/discussion-between-wren-jago-and-chris-g).

Comment: You are missing that getValues() return an Array of Arrays, not an Array of strings. Try getValues().flat() to get an Array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. This is what ended up working due to the data types, in case anyone sees this later

```js
function getDateColum(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master Rota")
  var dateHeaders = ss.getRange('E3:ND3').getValues();
  var date = new Date()
  date = date + ""
  date = date.slice(0,11)
  dateHeaders = dateHeaders[0].map(function(x){ return x.toString().substring(0, 11) })
  Logger.log(dateHeaders)
  Logger.log(date)
```

Thanks again